# React pass params with Axios post

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to pass a params to server using Axios.post but it didn't work with 404 error any ideas??

code:

```jsx
function Movie() {
  const { index } = useParams(); // get index from path /movie/:index

  const [movie, setMovie] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/movie", {
      params: { id: index },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        setMovie(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <body>
      abc
      {index}
      {movie.id}
    </body>
  );
}
```

Server:

```js
app.post('/movie', async (req, res)=>{
  let id= req.params.id;
  let movie=[];
  movie.push(id);
  res.send(movie); 
});
```

Comment: Your route does not have any [route parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters). You are passing a query string so should use `req.query.id`

Comment: @Kalman 404 means the request _did_ make it to the server. If the server was not started or not listening on port 3001, the error message would be completely different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 404 Error means that the path `/movie` cannot be found on the API. Perhaps ensure that the route on your server is named correctly.